# Setting up projects in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to setup a dev wamp server on my local machine so I can do some dev work without giving my boss a heart attack if something goes wrong.

I have wamp running and working just fine, the problem is the project I am working on was developed using `<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/` for all the paths.

The Document root of the server is D:/wamp/www which is correct for the dev server.

Is there a way that I can setup a project so that the relative document root for that particular project would be d:/wamp/www/project

I've tried to use vhosts and aliases to no avail. When I setup the vhost everything for the project worked fine but it was the only site on localhost.

Comment: You can, but you would have to stop using DOCUMENT_ROOT. Maybe it would be an alternative to set up multiple virtual hosts on the local machine (that are reachable only from your machine)?

Comment: Part of the problem is that I inherited this site and I'm worried that removing all the Document_Root entries will break the site. 
I was hoping that I would be able to have multiple projects running and there would be a way to set the Document_Root for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do that with a script like this one:

```
$basePath = dirname(__FILE__); // assuming this script is in D:/wamp/www
$projectPath = preg_replace('#('.$basePath.'/[^/]+)/.*#i', '\\1', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $projectPath;
```

The `preg_replace` line strips everything from the current script's path up to *BASE + 1 segment*. Then then the last line overwrites the current DOCUMENT_ROOT index from $_SERVER with the new path.

You can then set `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini:

```
auto_prepend_file = D:/wamp/www/prepend_script.php
```

Or .htaccess (in D:/wamp/www):

```
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend_script.php
```